# Getting Only value from Select Dropdown from ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue getting just the value from a dropdown. I have the following structure:

```
$scope.categories = [
  {id: 7, title: 'Peanut Butter'},
  {id: 4, title: 'Mustard'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Jelly'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Jam'},
  {id: 1, title: 'Mint Jelly'}
];
```

and I'm creating a  dropdown as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="testme.id" ng-options="c as c.title for c in categories track by c.id">
    <option value="">------</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="testme.pos" />

The dropdown generates fine
```

For example, if I put in "3" into "testme.pos" and select "Jam", but the model "testme" comes with the following example result:

```
{id: {id: 2, title: 'Jam'}, pos: 3 },
```

What I would like to see:

```
{id: 2, pos: 3}
```

Any help would be great. I created a plnkr: [Select Help](https://plnkr.co/edit/9RqCbD)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions: `ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in categories"`

Comment: No, this is not the answer I'm looking for. I'm aware of the docs and, as the plunker I linked to shows, it works. The problem is I want to set the id only. If the position is already filled in, changing the dropdown will override that value. This is why I only want to set the id.

Comment: And the docs, and the snippet I pasted right after the link, show how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-model="testme.id"` use `ng-model="testme"`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this is not the answer I'm looking for. As the plunker I linked to shows, it works. The problem is I want to set the id only. If the position is already filled in, changing the dropdown will override that value. This is why I only want to set the id. Thank you though for your help

Comment: try this, it will not override the position value on dropdown change.
`<select class="form-control" ng-model="testme.id" ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in categories track by c.id">`